# GDB exec Error: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I have an executable, which I can read symbols from (so it seems.) My problem is this: when it comes time to run, I get the following error:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/usr/src/etcetera/etcetera/bin/theExecutable.exe
Cannot exec  -c exec /home/usr/src/etcetera/etcetera/bin/theExecutable.exe.
Error: No such file or directory
During startup program exited with code 127
```

obviously, I have edited the directories here. I searched how to fix this on SO, and tried some of the following solutions:

[GDB cannot see source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543177/gdb-cannot-see-source-file)

[GDB can't find source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392190/gdb-cant-find-source-file)

[GDB won't load source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928876/gdb-can-not-load-source-file)

got onto this link:

https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html#Source-Path

and am trying to change the source file directory. (The source files are not in the same location as the executable, but instead are spread over a range of different places.) Unless I am mistaken, the way of doing this is to go:

`(gdb) directory /home/usr/src/etcetera/etcetera/rootDirectoryForSourcefiles`

and have the GDB search this directory. I have even tried changing directory into the source directory, and then running but still, it wants to try where the executable lives.

Am I completely missing the mark here in an obvious way, or is this likely to be quite obscure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are barking up the wrong tree. You problem has ~nothing to do with source files, and everything to do with your *executable* file.

It may be related to something in your `~/.gdbinit`, or your `~/.bashrc`, or the way you invoked GDB.

You should start by doing a basic sanity check:

```
env SHELL=/bin/sh gdb -nx /bin/date
(gdb) run
```

If that doesn't work, your GDB installation is screwed up.

If that does work, one of the three things I mentioned above is very likely the cause of your troubles.

Comment: yep, a colleague checked out my `~/.bashrc` and there was something quite wonky with that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it turned out that the shell wasn't set correctly in the `/etc/passwd` file.

To solve it, I opened the file with

```
sudo vipw
```

and added `/bin/bash` to the my account's data there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

export SHELL=/bin/sh

before running gdb

Answer (score 0):

I had met same problem. When my

```
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/tcsh
```

but I have only the file `.cshrc`, gdb reports the same error.

When I change SHELL:

```
setenv SHELL /bin/csh
```

Then everything goes fine.